# Variable voltage for GPIO windows IOT Core

Tags: c#, gpio, windows-10-iot-core

I have a windows IOT Core application which writes output to the GPIO pins and I need to have a variable voltage set on three pins to set an RGB lamp to any colour.

Problem is I can only set the pins to high value or low value, nothing in between:

```
private void SetupLeds()
{
    var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

    _redLED = gpio.OpenPin(18);
    _redLED.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);

    _greenLED = gpio.OpenPin(23);
    _greenLED.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);

    _blueLED = gpio.OpenPin(24);
    _blueLED.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);

}    

public void Yellow()
{
    _redLED.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
    _greenLED.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
    _blueLED.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
}

public void Red()
{
    _redLED.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
    _greenLED.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
    _blueLED.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction to be able to write a value between 1 and 0 on the pin I would appreciate it.

Maybe its not even possible for this version of Core IOT.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to leppie's comment I now realise that of course I need to use PWM.

So the question now is anyone know how to use PWM on Windows Core IOT?

Comment: That is what a digital port does, 1's and 0's, on or off. For an LED you could use PWM, or if available, a DAC.

Comment: Ahh of course {face palms} need to use PWM!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PWM is currently not supported. I am expecting it to be in later builds. In the meantime you could interface your RPi2 to an Arduino. You can access the PWM on the Arduino. See [this sample in the file ControlPage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/ms-iot/windows-remote-arduino-samples/tree/master/win10/remote-controlled-car/remote-controlled-car).

Mark Radbourne [MSFT]

Comment: any news here since the final IoT core version? I find it rather disappointing and isn't everyone starting with LEDs? :(

Answer (score 1):

We have added C# support for Software PWM and Hardware PWM in the [iot-devices project](https://github.com/jbienzms/iot-devices). You may also consult [this C++ example](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/arduino-wiring/StepperMotor.htm) of driving a stepper motor using Windows IoT Core and PWM.